# How to expand/collapse column in vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am working with vue.js with vuetify framework, i am trying to show/hide column. How can i do that with vue. In Vuetify documentation , there is only expand/collapse for row like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4S5Xs.png)

```js
export default {
        data: () => ({
            singleExpand: false,
            desserts: [
                {
                    name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
                    calories: 159,
                    fat: 6.0,
                    carbs: 24,
                    protein: 4.0,
                    sodium: 87,
                    calcium: '14%',
                    iron: '1%',
                },
                {
                    name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
                    calories: 237,
                    fat: 9.0,
                    carbs: 37,
                    protein: 4.3,
                    sodium: 129,
                    calcium: '8%',
                    iron: '1%',
                },
            ],
        }),
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<template>
    <v-container fluid>
        <v-switch v-model="singleExpand"
                  label="Expand Single Item"></v-switch>
        <v-data-iterator :items="desserts"
                         item-key="name"
                         :items-per-page="4"
                         :single-expand="singleExpand"
                         hide-default-footer>
            <template v-slot:default="{ items, isExpanded, expand }">
                <v-row>
                    <v-col v-for="item in items"
                           :key="item.name"
                           cols="12"
                           sm="6"
                           md="4"
                           lg="3">
                        <v-card>
                            <v-card-title>
                                <h4>{{ item.name }}</h4>
                            </v-card-title>
                            <v-switch :input-value="isExpanded(item)"
                                      :label="isExpanded(item) ? 'Expanded' : 'Closed'"
                                      class="pl-4 mt-0"
                                      @change="(v) => expand(item, v)"></v-switch>
                            <v-divider></v-divider>
                            <v-list v-if="isExpanded(item)"
                                    dense>
                                <v-list-item>
                                    <v-list-item-content>Calories:</v-list-item-content>
                                    <v-list-item-content class="align-end">
                                        {{ item.calories }}
                                    </v-list-item-content>
                                </v-list-item>
                                <v-list-item>
                                    <v-list-item-content>Fat:</v-list-item-content>
                                    <v-list-item-content class="align-end">
                                        {{ item.fat }}
                                    </v-list-item-content>
                                </v-list-item>
                            </v-list>
                        </v-card>
                    </v-col>
                </v-row>
            </template>
        </v-data-iterator>
    </v-container>
</template>
```

I want to make a dynamic column that can expand/collapse. here is what i expected to do. i really dont know how to make it, can i make it with vuetify or have to do with vue native.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4S5Xs.png)

Comment: Please provide some code to us that we can see how your code looks right now... also your problem will be easier to understand! Thanks!

Comment: thanks for your reaction @B0BBY, i have already specify my question

Comment: Hi Rangga! I've try your code and it seems to work correctly according to your requirements (you can hide any column). What's the issue?

Comment: Hi @jssDev, in my code above, it only hide/show the row, not column, you can check the image that i attached, my question is how can i hide the next column that trigerred by a button. specifically, i have 2 columns , we call A and B, each column has row. if i hit button in column A, the column B include the header and its row will hide, and the table will growth dynamically. how can i do that with vue.